# Why do I need to set the tail value to modify the head value in a Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list

I need to create a linked list in Python. I have looked into this explanation on how to create my linked list:

https://stackabuse.com/python-linked-lists/

But I have a few questions concerning why some things are necessary.

```
def add_list_item(self, item):
    # add an item at the end of the list

    if not isinstance(item, ListNode):
        item = ListNode(item)

    if self.head is None:
        self.head = item
    else:
       self.tail.next = item

    self.tail = item

    return
```

The issues are:

- Why should I replace the `self.tail.next` value, where the logical way to think is to change the `self.head.next` value directly (this does not work, though).
- Why changing the `self.tail.next` also changes the `self.head.next` value?
- Why do I need to reset the following value to make the linked list work?

`self.tail = item`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are adding the new item to the END of the list, which is pointed to by self.tail, the new item becomes the NEXT node after the current tail (self.tail.next). Since self.tail is a pointer to the LAST node of the list, it must now be set to point to the newly linked item, so self.tail = item.

Comment: And why self.tail.next also creates a new node in the self.head variable?

Comment: @MatheusSant'ana if self.head is None then it means the list is empty, so the new item becomes BOTH the tail AND the head of the list. self.head is never changed when a new item is added to a list which is not empty.